# CSS - text-decoration is not working for images

Tags: css

I have a image in my page, when i mouse over that image `text-decoration:underline;` *css* property is not working...

```
<div class='imgover'>
   click me<img  src='http://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo3w.png' alt='Img' />
</div>
```

css class is given below,

```
.imgover:hover
{    
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

refer this link http://jsfiddle.net/smanimani/cwnwK/1/

but the text-decoration is working fine for text, but it's not working for image...!

How do i solve this?

Thanks in advance....!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
.imgover:hover 
{     
border-bottom: 1px solid red; 
}
```

Comment: Hi @Jawad... Thanks for ur reply.... `border-bottom` is also a good solution for this.. but, i want to know, why 'text-decoration' is not working....

Comment: text-decoration is for text - as Mark said in the other comment, the only CSS property related to text that works for images is text-align.

Answer (score 0):

change from :

```
.imgover:hover {    
  text-decoration:underline;
}
```

to this:

```
.imgover:hover {     
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000; 
}
```

`text-decoration` is used for text, `border-bottom` can be used for everything.

The only text-related CSS property that works by images is `text-align`.